# How to improve CPU usage when automatically "locking" a (WPF) application using Window.PreviewMouseMoveEvent?

Tags: c#, wpf, idle-timer, user-inactivity

Currently I'm using

```
 EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Window),
                                   Window.PreviewMouseMoveEvent,
                                   new MouseEventHandler(OnPreviewMouseMove));
```

where `OnPreviewMouseMove` just calls `Stop()` and `Start()` on the timer used to handle automatic timeout of my application (users should re-enter credentials after a period of inactivity).

I've noticed that this solution uses quite a bit of CPU power (as in, 3-12% on a Core i7 when I'm jittering the mouse over the window), so I wonder if there might be a better way to handle this. I understand that the jittery mouse movement and relatively low CPU usage won't be a real problem, but I am open to better ways to handle this.

I'm also unsure whether this can be made to work for non-WPF applications (my guess is I'll need different events in this case), but that might be matter for another question.

Comment: Do you need to know if the user is moving the mouse while your program is focused or would just knowing the mouse moved in general (even if your program was minimized) be acceptable so that your timeout worked on the same clock that the screensaver uses?

Comment: @Scott I would guess the screensaver clock would work. If that would work even when the screensaver is disabled of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Windows API call [`GetLastInputInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646302(v=vs.85).aspx) to figure out when the last keyboard press or mouse movement happened. This is the same timer that the screensaver uses to figure out when to turn on.

Here is a wrapper class I have used in other projects. The `Idle` event runs on the current `SynchronizationContext` or a threadpool thread if there is not one set.

```
/// <summary>
/// A timer that raises the <see cref="Idle"/> event when it detects the session 
/// </summary>
public sealed class SystemIdleTimer : IDisposable
{
    private readonly System.Threading.Timer _timer;
    private readonly SynchronizationContext _synchronizationContext;

    /// <summary>
    /// This event is rasied when the sysstem's idle time is greater than <see cref="MaxIdleTime"/>.
    /// This event is posted to the SynchronizationContext that the constructor was run under.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler Idle;

    /// <summary>
    /// The amount of idle time that must pass before the <see cref="Idle"/> event is raised.
    /// </summary>
    public TimeSpan MaxIdleTime { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Is the user currently detected as idle;
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsDetectedIdle { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new timer with a specified trigger level and a check frequency of once a minute.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="maxIdleTime">The amount of idle time that must pass before the <see cref="Idle"/> event is raised.</param>
    public SystemIdleTimer(TimeSpan maxIdleTime)
        : this(maxIdleTime, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new timer with a specified trigger level and a check frequency.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="maxIdleTime">The amount of idle time that must pass before the <see cref="Idle"/> event is raised.</param>
    /// <param name="checkInterval">The frequency in miliseconds to check the idle timer.</param>
    public SystemIdleTimer(TimeSpan maxIdleTime, TimeSpan checkInterval)
    {
        MaxIdleTime = maxIdleTime;
        _synchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(TimerCallback, null, checkInterval, checkInterval);
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer.Dispose();
        Idle = null;
    }

    private void TimerCallback(object state)
    {
        var idleTime = GetIdleTime();
        if (idleTime > MaxIdleTime)
        {
            if (!IsDetectedIdle)
            {
                IsDetectedIdle = true;
                OnIdle();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            IsDetectedIdle = false;
        }
    }

    private void OnIdle()
    {
        var idle = Idle;
        if (idle != null)
        {
            if (_synchronizationContext != null)
            {
                _synchronizationContext.Post(state => idle(this, EventArgs.Empty), null);
            }
            else
            {
                idle(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the amout of time the system has been idle.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A TimeSpan representing the idle time for the session.</returns>
    public static TimeSpan GetIdleTime()
    {
        try
        {
            uint idleMiliseconds = 0;
            LASTINPUTINFO lastInputInfo = new LASTINPUTINFO();
            lastInputInfo.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(lastInputInfo);
            lastInputInfo.dwTime = 0;

            uint systemUpTime = GetTickCount();

            if (GetLastInputInfo(ref lastInputInfo))
            {
                uint lastInputTime = lastInputInfo.dwTime;

                if (lastInputTime > systemUpTime)
                {
                    // The elapsed time is stored as a DWORD value. Therefore, the time will wrap around to zero if the system is run continuously for 49.7 days.
                    // so, we need a bit more math...

                    // how far between last input and the current time rolling over to 0
                    idleMiliseconds = (uint.MaxValue - lastInputTime);

                    // add that to the current ticks
                    idleMiliseconds = idleMiliseconds + systemUpTime;
                }
                else
                {
                    idleMiliseconds = systemUpTime - lastInputTime;
                }
            }


            return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(idleMiliseconds);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return TimeSpan.Zero;
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct LASTINPUTINFO
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public UInt32 cbSize;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public UInt32 dwTime;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO plii);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern uint GetTickCount();
}
```

Comment: I came across this, but flinched when I read `The tick count when the last input event was received (see LASTINPUTINFO) is not guaranteed to be incremental. In some cases, the value might be less than the tick count of a prior event. For example, this can be caused by a timing gap between the raw input thread and the desktop thread or an event raised by SendInput, which supplies its own tick count.´ Along with the need for the marshalling which I am trying to avoid. The idea to check based on a timer is something that might lead somewhere though. Thanks!

Comment: The `if (lastInputTime > systemUpTime)` block of code handles that condition the documentation was talking about it being non incremental. Also, that third sentence is saying "if you did a `GetTickCount()` from inside a `OnPreviewMouseMove` and save it, the value you get may appear "newer" than the result of `GetLastInputInfo()`". But we are not relying on a time from inside a windows message event handler so it does not matter to us. Also unless you plan on running on platforms that you can't  do P/Invoke there is nothing wrong with doing marsaling.